# how to pick server responses using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how can i pick the error messages and display them.All actions have a success message and can also generate errors,I can pick the success but i have failed to pick the error messages.why is it that i can't see the error messages side of thingsThis is what i have tried so far

```
function ajax(action,id){
action = 'save';
if(action =="save")
    data = $("#userinfo").serialize()+"&action="+action;
else if(action == "delete"){
    data = "action="+action+"&item_id="+id;
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "ajax.php", 
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){

        if(response.success == "1"){
            if(action == "save"){
                $(".dert-form").fadeOut("fast",function(){
                  alert("here first");
                }); 
            }
            else if(action == "delete"){
                alert("here  to delete");
            }
        }else{alert(response.msg);}
    },
    error: function(res){
        alert("Unexpected error! Try again.");
    }
});
}
```

And this is my ajax.php

```
/* Check for blanks */ 
foreach( as $field => $value)              
{   if ($value == "")                          
{
    $blanks[] = $field;
}
}
if(isset($blanks))                                
{
 header('HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict');
     exit("You have blank fields.  Please enter the required information:  ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTP Status codes. When you set the following response code in your PHP code, it will trigger the error callback on your ajax call.

```
http_response_code(409);
```

Comment: +1 for this one line,i had bypassed it ,but it led me to a hint

Comment: i have tried to edit my code as above and a redo of the ajax as in my comments to Sid but no display?? why?/

Answer (score 0):

You will get it like this

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}
```

Comment: +1 for following up.When i replace my error function with yours ,i still get no display of the message "You have blank fields.  Please enter the required information:"

Comment: i have updated my code to the above on the php side but my error function set as yours still doesn't display the eroor message.Thanks otherwise for your advice it has pushed me  somewhere to the light

Comment: i have edited  like so with .error as a paragragh to hold the message but still no display, why??  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
     if(xhr.status == "409"){
      var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
     $(".error").html(err);} 
   }

Comment: What you are getting in xhr, staus and error please debug it and tell me

Comment: i do not have a debuger,i simply run it and wait for the expected output

Answer (score 0):

The ajax part seems ok. The error probably is in your php functions, but depends of the contents of the data you have, so it's hard to tell.

Anyway, I think it's important to comment that the correct solution is to return a http error code in the php response, so **jQuery evaluates the response as an error and not a success**.

Comment: Iam checking for any empty fileds on a form and trying to get a server reply.well they are inputs and if any /all are empty then that is how iam setting the error to be returned.but it blinkswhen i try to submitt an empty form and i do not get to see the error. as in alert(response.msg).i have looked closely and seen that it blinks the alert("Unexpected error! Try again."); and diaappears very fast. +1 for studying my situation .show me how to implement the correct solution

Comment: you can try with a fake response message to see if js gets it.

Comment: @davod ruiz Thanks for your suggestion but with ny php code update ,it is still not displaying the error message